# Fly-back converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, simulation, matlab, flyback

I'm trying to get 2 isolated outputs (5V and 3V from 12V DC supply) using a single flyback converter by adding one more secondary winding on the flyback transformer.
Following is the Simulink model I've built but I'm not getting the required output. Please help!
[image]

Comment: Some time ago i've had problems with isolated dc-dc converter in MATLAB, and the main problem is in wrong transformer parameters. If you've ignored a few of them (mutual inductance or so) - then it might not work. After that, try to make components more real - all parasitic parameters to capacitors (ESR, about 0.1 Ohm)

Comment: thanks....I'll try with parasitic parameters but i'm looking for the corrections regarding topology what i've used...

Comment: You haven't provided anywhere near enough information for anyone to possibly answer your quesiton.  What is the output voltages on the secondaries? What are the values you're using for...well, everything in the simulation.  What are the inductances of the windings? Also, I don't see any feedback (isolated or otherwise), and Flyback's must have feedback via some means to function properly.  When adding another winding, one need only regulate one secondary winding, which is the 'master'.  If your converter worked without feedback at first, it likely will not if you change the output load.